# Code to zip uploaded files fails to delete temporary files

Tags: php, zip, unlink

I guys, i'm writting code to upload file, zip them and delete tmp file.
But when i use **unlink** function, it do not remove all file, someone can explain to me why ?

**Concerned php code :**

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$target_path = 'img/products/';
$zip->open($target_path.$id_insert.'.zip', ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);
$img_count = $_POST['count_file'];
for ($i = 1; $i <= $img_count; $i++){
    $temp = 'img'.$i;
    $file = $i.'-'.$id_insert.'-'.$_FILES[$temp]['name'];
    $path = $target_path.basename($file); 
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$temp]['tmp_name'], $path)) {
        $zip->addFile($path, basename($file));
        $files_to_delete[] = $path;
    }
} 
$zip->close();
foreach($files_to_delete AS $file){
    //unlink(dirname(__FILE__).'/'.$path);
}
```

Comment: You should be getting `E_WARNING` if it doesn't work, can you please post it here? I'm guessing there are some privilege issues.

Comment: I get a "No such file or directory" but the path is correct and work for another uploaded file Oo :)

Comment: They are another way to add file to a zip archive without create file ? ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach($files_to_delete AS $file){
    //unlink(dirname(__FILE__).'/'.$path);
}
```

In this block you should replace $path with $file since that's what you're foreaching them as. You get the error because after you unlink $path the first time, the file at $path is unlinked, but every other iteration of it tries to delete the same file (which is the last one assigned to the $path variable).